# Synchronizing thread access and write in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a multithreaded port scanner app written in C#, and I want to print some stuff both to the console and a log file as the app runs. For this reason, I have the following helper class, which works fine in writing both to a log file and the console.

```
public class Output
{
    private const string LOG_DIRECTORY = "Logs";
    private readonly string LogDirPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), LOG_DIRECTORY);

    private static Output _outputSingleton;
    private static Output OutputSingleton {
        get {
            if (_outputSingleton == null)
            {
                _outputSingleton = new Output();
            }
            return _outputSingleton;
        }
    }

    public StreamWriter SW { get; set; }

    public Output()
    {
        EnsureLogDirectoryExists();
        InstantiateStreamWriter();
    }

    ~Output()
    {
        if (SW != null)
        {
            try
            {
                SW.Dispose();
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException) { } // object already disposed - ignore exception
        }
    }

    public static void WriteLine(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        OutputSingleton.SW.WriteLine(str);
    }

    public static void Write(string str)
    {
        Console.Write(str);
        OutputSingleton.SW.Write(str);
    }

    private void InstantiateStreamWriter()
    {
        long ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        string logFilename = "scan_" + ticks.ToString() + ".txt";
        string filePath = Path.Combine(LogDirPath, logFilename);
        try
        {
            SW = new StreamWriter(filePath);
            SW.AutoFlush = true;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Access denied. Could not instantiate StreamWriter using path: {0}.", filePath), ex);
        }
    }

    private void EnsureLogDirectoryExists()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(LogDirPath))
        {
            try
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(LogDirPath);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Access denied. Could not create log directory using path: {0}.", LogDirPath), ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that since my app is multithreading sometimes I get multiple log files created, each of them partially written, and sometimes I get exception thrown since one thread cannot access the same place to write while it is being used by another thread. Is there any way to make my above `Output` class multithreaded too, so that I avoid the above mentioned problems?

Comment: Use a constant file name, instead of create a new one each time you access the function. Then, use `lock` to write to it. Or create an `ConcurrentBag<string>`, add the logs and in the end write it to a file.

Comment: @Magnetron My task is to write them as the program runs, I was previously writing at the end, but was requested to change it. Also, the file name should basically have a name that includes the DateTime in ticks when the file is created.

Comment: Then, when the program starts, create the filename that will be used to all threads. When you're going to write, use `lock` to ensure that only 1 thread has access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a single file and a `lock` strategy should do the job:

```
private Object m_Lock = new Object();

public static void WriteLine(string str)
{
    lock (m_Lock)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        OutputSingleton.SW.WriteLine(str);
    }
}

public static void Write(string str)
{
    lock (m_Lock)
    {
        Console.Write(str);
        OutputSingleton.SW.Write(str);
    }
}

private void InstantiateStreamWriter()
{
    string logFilename = "Log.txt";
    string filePath = Path.Combine(LogDirPath, logFilename);

    try
    {
        SW = new StreamWriter(filePath);
        SW.AutoFlush = true;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Access denied. Could not instantiate StreamWriter using path: {0}.", filePath), ex);
    }
}
```

The problem here comes with the shared lock. If you use the same lock on multiple methods, then locking one method locks other methods as well (in your case `Write` and `WriteLine`). It looks totally fine to me since they are strictly related... but this may create a bottleneck if the methods are called very frequently. On the other side, separate locks would make the methods run independently and this is even worse.

Try to merge the two methods into one as follows, so you don't have to care about handling locks on separate methods:

```
public static void WriteLine(String str, Boolean line = true)
{
    lock (m_Lock)
    {
        if (line)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            OutputSingleton.SW.WriteLine(str);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(str);
            OutputSingleton.SW.Write(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, misstyped the object name, I fix it now!

Comment: Shouldn't a lock also be used in the OutputSingleton Getter? It kind of looks like his two threads have caused two different Output objects to be returned.

Comment: Ah, nice spot... I don't think this can cause problems as long as the methods are locked. A non-singleton, full static pattern would be better here, in my opinion, that's sure.

Comment: nevermind. I failed to notice that his singleton is private and used inside the write and writeline methods.